# SQL Server UNPIVOT table by combining two rows based on condition, using a SINGLE unpivot

Tags: sql-server, row, conditional-statements, rows, unpivot

**I have a big query which gives a table result looking like this:**

```
[Date]          [Type]  TC1   TC2    TC3
..........................................
'2014-01-01'    T       11    22     33
'2014-01-01'    C       44    55     66
'2014-01-02'    T       111   222    333
'2014-01-02'    C       444   555    666
'2014-01-03'    T       1111  2222   3333
'2014-01-04'    C       4444  5555   6666
```

**I want to make it look like this:**

```
[Date]          Cntr      TValue      CValue
............................................
'2014-01-01'    TC1       11          44
'2014-01-01'    TC2       22          55
'2014-01-01'    TC3       33          66
'2014-01-02'    TC1       111         444
'2014-01-02'    TC2       222         555
'2014-01-02'    TC3       333         666
'2014-01-03'    TC1       1111        4444
'2014-01-03'    TC2       2222        5555
'2014-01-03'    TC3       3333        6666
```

**I managed to do this by unpivoting two times and then join the results.
The query I made is this**:

```
SELECT A.[Date],A.Cntr,A.TValue,B.CValue
FROM
(
    SELECT [Date],Cntr,TValue
    FROM TB 
    UNPIVOT
    (
    TValue
    FOR Cntr IN (TC1,TC2,TC3)
    ) u
    WHERE  [Type] = 'T' AND u.[Type] = 'T'
) A
JOIN
(
    SELECT [Date],Cntr,CValue
    FROM TB 
    UNPIVOT
    (
    CValue
    FOR Cntr IN (TC1,TC2,TC3)
    ) u
    WHERE  [Type] = 'C' AND u.[Type] = 'C'
) B
ON B.[Date] = A.[Date] AND A.[Cntr] = B.[Cntr]
```

My problem is that TB table comes from a big and time consuming query and, given the fact that it will be called thousands of times during my stored procedure, I dont want to waste precious time by inserting its many rows in a temporary table.

**Is there a way to solve this by using a single unpivot, or using a better approach ?**
Also, this has to run on **SQLServer >= 2005**

SqlFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f4bf/1)

Thank you!

Comment: Are Date/Type constrained to be unique in TB? If not, i.e. 2 records with type `T`, and 2 records with type 'C' on a single date, then how would you match each T and C without creating a Cartesian product, or would a Cartesian product be the required result?

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding! Yes, Date and Type will always be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since (`Date/Type`) are constrained to be unique in `TB`, then you can `UNPIVOT` and then `PIVOT` to avoid the join, MAX(Value) is an arbitrary aggregation, since there can only be one value anyway.

```
SELECT  pvt.Date,
        pvt.Cntr,
        TValue = pvt.T,
        CValue = pvt.C
FROM    TB
        UNPIVOT (Value FOR Cntr IN (TC1, TC2, TC3)) AS upvt
        PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR [Type] IN (C, T)) AS pvt;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f4bf/7)**

This results in half the number of reads (as you'd probably expect). IO Statistics show:

**UNPIVOT/PIVOT**

> Table 'TB'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

**UNPIVOT/UNPIVOT/JOIN**

> Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'TB'. Scan count 2, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

And a simpler execution plan (UNPIVOT/PIVOT on top):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I wouldn't have thought at this solution. I will use it in my SP, since its performance is better!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using `cross apply` and conditional aggregation:

```
select [date], [cntr],
       max(case when [type] = 'T' then val end) as TValue,
       max(case when [type] = 'C' then val end) as CValue
from (<your query here>) t cross apply
     (values ([date], [type], 'tc1', tc1),
             ([date], [type], 'tc2', tc2),
             ([date], [type], 'tc3', tc3)
     ) vals([date], [type], cntr, val)
group by [date], [cntr];
```

EDIT:

I missed the SQL Server 2005 condition.  The syntax before `values()` is:

```
select [date], [cntr],
       max(case when [type] = 'T' then val end) as TValue,
       max(case when [type] = 'C' then val end) as CValue
from (<your query here>) t cross apply
     (select [date], [type], 'tc1', tc1 union all
      select [date], [type], 'tc2', tc2 union all
      select [date], [type], 'tc3', tc3
     ) vals([date], [type], cntr, val)
group by [date], [cntr];
```

Comment: I thought about Cross Apply, but thag UNION ALL part backed me down. I will give it a try though:)